# Formatting error with .LineStyle and .Weight-VBA-

Tags: vba, excel

I am running this code to fix the fomatting in my workbook and it seems to be working fine in some cases but in some others it stops with a "1004 Error" msg in the .Linestyle or .Weight.Anyone has any suggestions on what might be going wrong here? Thanks a lot!

'Fit the widths of the columns & fix the formatting

```
Columns("A:D").AutoFit`

With Sheets("Sheet1")`
    .Cells.Font.Size = 8`
End With`

Set rng1 = Columns("A:F")`
Set rng2 = Rows("1:10")`

With rng1.Borders`
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous`
    .Weight = xlHairline`
End With`

With rng2.Borders`
    .LineStyle = xlNone`
End With`
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ranges **inside** the `With Sheets("Sheet1")... End With`.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    .Cells.Font.Size = 8
    Set rng1 = .Columns("A:F")
    Set rng2 = .Rows("1:10")
End With

With rng1.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlHairline
End With`

With rng2.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

You lost the parent worksheet association when you stepped out of the With ... End With.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It seems that i still get the error though maybe it interferes with the previous formatting and when i refresh it causes an error. could that be the case that i need to take the bordering away before i refresh and put it back? or any other suggestion?

Comment: No, the border formatting should just take the new settings. fwiw, I did run through that code and it runs fine.

Comment: That is the weird part that it runs fine sometimes and some others it doesnt!